# How to help search engines to search in your AJAX driven website?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, robots.txt

I make a ajax driven website. So when you click a link the website is updating without navigating to other url. But how can i prevent a search-engine (like google) to only index my homepage.

I have some ideas:

```
<a href="?p=contact" onclick="updatepage('contact')" />
```

or maybe make a robots.txt.
Can you help me?